# How to store the machine learning model pickle to azure blob and retrieve it/

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, pickle

I have created a pickle from my machine learning model and it is getting saved in local. I want to push it to azure blob storage and want to retrieve it later. How can I do it using python 3. Please help.

'''

```
#model
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#Creating the pickle file finalized_model.sav on my local

mypickle = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(regressor, open(mupickle, 'wb'))
```

'''

```
I tried following for .csv importing and pushing from azure, but don't know how to do with pickle files.
```

'''

```
with BytesIO() as input_blob:

    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='*****', 
    account_key='*********************************************************************')
    block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream('blobcontainer', 'claims.csv', input_blob)
    input_blob.seek(0) 
    dataframe_blobdata = pd.read_csv(input_blob)

    #transforming the data in between

    output = dataframe_blobdata.to_csv (index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")

    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('secondforblobcontainer', 'OutFilePy.csv', output)
```

'''

Comment: May I know if my answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you just want to upload your picfile which names `finalized_model.sav` to Azure Storage.

Then I would suggest you use `azure-storage-blob` SDK to upload a blob. Here is an official sample: [Code examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#code-examples).

In details, firstly you need to get the connection string of your storage account from portal, then you create a `BlobServiceClient` with the connection string, after that you can create a container client by `blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)`. 
Finally, you can create a blob client and then upload the local file based on its path.

And it is also easy to download it back from Azure Storage. The sample for [downloading blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#download-blobs):

```
with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
```

Comment: If you use the old version SDK, there is also a tutorial for your reference: [Manage blobs with Python v2.1 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy). Basically, the key point is `block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    container_name, blob_name, full_path_to_local_file)`